# in csh if-statement giving error as "if: Badly formed number."

Tags: if-statement, csh

when i run the below code in my csh shell it is giving Error as `if: Badly formed number`.

```
#!/bin/csh

setenv KERNEL_VER `uname -r`

if ( "$KERNEL_VER" ==*"el6"* ) then
  echo "Kernel version is OEL6"
elif ( "$KERNEL_VER" == *"el7"* ) then
  echo "Kernel version is OEL7"
else
  echo "Only OEL6 or OEL7 are supported"
  exit 1
fi
```

i OS is a OEL7 so the control should go inside the "elif" section.

Instead i am getting the below error.

```
if: Badly formed number.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your `if` statements look correct. Please add a statement `echo "#dbg : KERNEL_VER=XX${KERNEL_VER}XX"` and update your Q with that output.